# Date of birth year not show in calender

Tags: formula-field, custom-field

I have a custom field of date of birth, which only showing 2017 to 2023 year in calendar. Please let me know how can I select the year 1989 and above.

Comment: post your code how you are trying to access

Comment: If you are willing to use Visualforce, there are custom datepickers that will give you greater range

Answer (score 0):

The Classic UI only goes back one year and forward five. There is an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Br31AAC) to have this enhanced. The Lightning Experience (LEX), however, goes back 100 years and forward 50 years. This is just one of many things that make LEX an option one might consider for moving towards Lightning.